# How can I transform a shellcode into raw bytes ? (Python)

Tags: python, byte, shellcode, raw

I have a simple shellcode like this :

buf =("\xfc\xe8\x8f\x00\x00\x00\x60\x31\xd2\x89\xe5\x64\x8b\x52\x30"
"\x8b\x52\x0c\x8b\x52\x14\x0f\xb7\x4a\x26\x8b\x72\x28\x31\xff"
"\x31\xc0\xac\x3c\x61\x7c\x02\x2c\x20\xc1\xcf\x0d\x01\xc7\x49")....

And I want (using Python) to change it to raw bytes like this example : 0x69,0x16,0x69,0x02,0x68,0x25,0xaa,0xaa,0xaa,0xca,0x9b,0x69,0x38,0x68,0x23,0x69,0x0f,0xce,0x68,0x21,0xf8,0x9a,0x68,0x21,0xf8,0xa6,0x68,0x21,0xf8,0xbe,0xa5,0x68,0x1d,0xe0,0x8c,0x68,0x21,0xd8,0x82....

(The comma is important). How can I do that ?

Comment: Are these two examples meant to represent the same data?

Comment: Yes indeed, I want to "convert" the shellcode in this way.